# Unknown identifier error in nested FOREACH statement check

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Looks like a simple error, but I'm unable to find anything specific about it, so hope you can shed some light on what is going on here.

Basically i'm trying to iterate through two sets of data, create elements for the first set and relate to them elements from the second set based on some condition. Condition check is also made via "foreach trick", therefore 2 levels of nested `FOREACH`'s

```
FOREACH (plc IN [{name:'bar2',id:'pepe'},{name:'foo2',id:'papa'},{name:'foo3',id:'paps'}] |
   MERGE (place:Place {id:plc.id})
   ON CREATE SET place = plc

   FOREACH (evt IN [{placename:'foo2',id:'pewpew'},{placename:'foo2',id:'powpow'},{placename:'bar2',id:'pawpaw'},{placename:'bar2',id:'pwaaagh'},{placename:'foo3',id:'pwaaagh'}] |

      FOREACH (ignoreme in CASE WHEN evt.placename = plc.name THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
         CREATE (e:Event)-[rel:IN]->(place) 
         SET e=evt
)))
```

Happily giggling `Neo4j` throws at me `Unknown identifier "e"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a bug.
You can work around it, by splitting the longer create pattern into two, so that the `e` variable is created.

```
FOREACH (plc IN [{name:'bar2',id:'pepe'},{name:'foo2',id:'papa'},{name:'foo3',id:'paps'}] |
   MERGE (place:Place {id:plc.id})
   ON CREATE SET place = plc

   FOREACH (evt IN [{placename:'foo2',id:'pewpew'},{placename:'foo2',id:'powpow'},{placename:'bar2',id:'pawpaw'},{placename:'bar2',id:'pwaaagh'},{placename:'foo3',id:'pwaaagh'}] |

      FOREACH (ignoreme in CASE WHEN evt.placename = plc.name THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
         CREATE (e:Event)
         CREATE (e)-[rel:IN]->(place) 
         SET e=evt
)))
```

Comment: Thanks, wil try it out.

Comment: Seems to be working just fine, have no idea why I didn't tryed it before, thank you! Btw, i'm curiosu, is there any way to RETURN results of foreach's creations at the end?

Answer (score 2):

I always suggest trying with `UNWIND` before `FOREACH`.

```
WITH
  [{name:'bar2',id:'pepe'},{name:'foo2',id:'papa'},{name:'foo3',id:'paps'}] AS plcs,
  [{placename:'foo2',id:'pewpew'},{placename:'foo2',id:'powpow'},{placename:'bar2',id:'pawpaw'},{placename:'bar2',id:'pwaaagh'},{placename:'foo3',id:'pwaaagh'}] AS evts
UNWIND plcs AS plc
MERGE (place:Place {id:plc.id})
WITH place, plc, evts
UNWIND evts AS evt
WITH place, plc, evt
WHERE evt.placename = plc.name
CREATE (e:Event)-[:IN]->(place)
  SET e=evt
```

Comment: I was in fact trying unwind but it was leading to creation of duplicated events in case when there was a place without matching event... Something to do with how multiple unwinds make cartesian products and how do they behave. 
But i was creating events on second unwind before making relationship based on equality, which lead to 3x5 events being created, i'll try this one out, but i don't understand if there is 15 fields in memory at point of comparison will it lead to creation of duplicates, as duplicated fields will match <>?

Comment: Oh wait looks like i lost in my own concept, anyway, thanks, will try it out shortly, 
Yes, logically it looks like it does the same thing as my foreaches...

Comment: Tested out, you forgot to put place in last unwind. ALso i don't know what is difference but it seems that `<>` does nothing, nodes appended in a random order (looks like), but `=` works. I made some edits to your query if you dont mind, this one seems to be working just fine and yield same results as foreach's. Yet i think i will go with latter as i find it a bit more clear. As far as i understand there is no difference between this two approaches performance-wise.